# Aligning batch output into columns

Tags: text, batch-file, cmd, alignment

I have a batch file that takes variables of variable length. For example output is like this:

```
%name% - %size% - %percentage% - %percentMIN% - %percentMAX%
%name% - %size% - %percentage% - %percentMIN% - %percentMAX%
%name% - %size% - %percentage% - %percentMIN% - %percentMAX%
%name% - %size% - %percentage% - %percentMIN% - %percentMAX%
%name% - %size% - %percentage% - %percentMIN% - %percentMAX%
```

Because the first 2 columns vary in length the output looks over all the place. Is there any way in a batch file to have the columns align? I've done some researching and it seems like there is a way to do it by padding the beginning bunch of characters with spaces? But that doesn't seem to work? Is there maybe another way?

Comment: ok, the only way you can achieve your desired response using batch and a .txt file is by setting a maximum length for the name and the number of digits in the size. ( A number like 15 would seem favourable ).  Then you would have to use the soloution in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file) to find the length of each `%name%` and `%size%` and then create a var which would account for these spaces as well as the name or size. This way each would be the same length in the text file. The ultimate soloution would be to:

Comment: Find the length of the all the `%name%` and `%size%` variables, determine which is the largest for the both, and replace the maximum number set (suggest to be 15) with that of the size of the largest length name and size, and in this way, your "cell padding" would take up as little space as possible, and though this would add alot of code to your program it would make it better and able to be used for more things (after adaptation)

Answer (score 5):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "spaces=                               "
SET "somethingelse=Some other data"
SET "name=abc"
SET /a size=123
CALL :formatout
SET "name=abcdefghijkl"
SET /a size=12345678
CALL :formatout
SET "name=a"
SET /a size=3
CALL :formatout

GOTO :EOF

:formatout
CALL :padright name 18
CALL :padleft size 13
ECHO +%name%+%size%+%somethingelse%
GOTO :eof

:padright
CALL SET padded=%%%1%%%spaces%
CALL SET %1=%%padded:~0,%2%%
GOTO :eof

:padleft
CALL SET padded=%spaces%%%%1%%
CALL SET %1=%%padded:~-%2%%
GOTO :eof
```

This demo should set you on the right track...

output is

```
+abc               +          123+Some other data
+abcdefghijkl      +     12345678+Some other data
+a                 +            3+Some other data
```

---

How it works (in response to comment)

```
:formatout
CALL :padright name 18
CALL :padleft size 13
ECHO +%name%+%size%+%somethingelse%
GOTO :eof
```

Let's start with the `:formatout` routine. It calls :pad???` for each of the required padding operations, then strings the results together for form an output line.

`:padright` requires two parameters. The first is the name of the variable whose contents are to be padded and the second the length to which they are to be padded.

```
CALL SET padded=%%%1%%%spaces%
```

uses a parsing trick. The `call` executes the `set` in a `cmd` subshell. The instruction executed in that subshell is

```
SET padded=%%.%1.%%.%spaces%
```

where I've used `.` to separate the syntactic elements.

`%%` here is an `escaped-%` as `%` is its own escape character (other awkward characters like `&`,`>`,`<`, `)` etc. are escaped by `^` eg. `^&`. You need to `escape` a character if you want that character to be interpreted literally instead of having its special meaning within batch syntax. Hence, if you want to `echo` a `>` character, you need to `escape` the `>` (ie `^>`) to tell batch that it is the *literal* that is required, not a redirection operation.

`%1` is replaced by the first parameter supplied to the routine, `name` in the example.

So what is *actually* executed is

```
set padded=%name%%spaces%
```

stringing a goodly number of spaces onto the end of the current value of the variable `name` (Note that this post is so old that it predates the use of the `set "var=value"` syntax I now use)

consequently, `padded` now contains the value of `name` padded with a number of spaces.

```
CALL SET %1=%%padded:~0,%2%%
```

Second verse - [same as the first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4gyG2UU9J4) - well, almost. The `set` command executed is
SET %1.=.%%.padded:~0,.%2.%%

or

```
SET name=%padded:~0,18%
```

since the second parameter provided to `:padright` is `18`.

and this command assigns the first 18 characters of `padded` to `name`.

`:padleft` works the same way, but adding the the spaces before the value of the variable, then selecting the *last* (second parameter value) characters.

Comment: Can you please explain how does :padright and :padleft work?

Answer (score 0):

```
 set test=A test
        set spce=                 .   
        set spce2=%spce:~0,16%
        set ntest=%test:~0,16%%spce2%
        set ntest2=%ntest:~0,16%

ECHO 123456789012345678  >> c:\temp\testfile.txt
echo %ntest2%^|other field>> c:\temp\testfile.txt
```

Comment: You can do a set /P test=<variable.txt to pick input from a file.(one variable) to produce output .  Also, you can set up loop  (for statement) and produce more variables by repeating above codes for other variables .. for example echo %ntest2%,%ntest3%,etc.   All will be fixed and aligned .. in above case, it will be 16 characters max for %ntest2%.  Above will be