# How I get the position of a character from a string in batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a result string saved in a variable `RES`, this result is something like `2.3/5.0` I would like to get the part before the "`/`" and sending it to the batch output through an `ECHO` command. I have been searching how can I do this using batch commands, but only getting results of making substring to a fixed position, but how can I know this position?
If i would knew the position the only thing I should probably do is:

```
ECHO %RES:~0,pos%
```

Then the question is: how I get this position from the string? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want the position itself, you can apply the strlen function from [How do you get the string length in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file) to the result below, but if you just want that prefix, you can simply do:

```
set "res=2.3/5.0"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=/" %%i in ("%res%") do (set prefix=%%i)
```

Comment: `tokens=1` is the default. You can omit it.

Comment: Actually that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!!! Instead of getting the position and then cuting I can get all at once. :)

Answer (score 6):

Why looking for the position of the delimiter instead of just using it?

```
for /f "delims=/" %%i in ("%RES%") do echo %%i
```