# How to extract version number in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I need to extract the Major , Minor and Revision numbers from a string and to achieve this I'm trying to split a string in a batch file using a '.' character as the delimiter.

For ex:
If the user enters **1.0.2** in the command prompt 
I should be able to extract

- 1 - Major version,
- 0 - Minor version and
- 2 - Revision

I'm trying to use the FOR command to achieve this, but just not getting through. Can anyone help me out with the extracting part

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL 
set /p "ReleaseVersion=Please specify the software release version : "

:nextVar
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%ReleaseVersion%") do (
   set %%a
   set ReleaseVersion=%%b
)
if defined ReleaseVersion goto nextVar

@PAUSE
```

Comment: This would be far easier as a console/shell JavaScript or PowerShell file. Is there a reason you're using Batch files instead?

Comment: Yes I need to incorporate this in my existing batch file scripts

Comment: Just a note: cmd.exe is not DOS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go...

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL 
set /p "ReleaseVersion=Please specify the software release version : "

for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=." %%a in ("%ReleaseVersion%") do (
   set Major=%%a
   set Minor=%%b
   set Revision=%%c
)

echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%
```

Input/output:

> Please specify the software release version : 1.0.2
>
> Major: 1, Minor: 0, Revision: 2

Comment: Think I fumbled with the tokens. Thanks for the solution

Answer (score 6):

I recently discovered an interesting trick that allows to split a string based on a delimiter *without using `for` command*, so I couldn't resist the temptation to post it here. This question also represent a different way to use my method (split string in more than 2 different variables). Here it is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p "ReleaseVersion=Please specify the software release version : "

set "v=Minor"
set "Major=%ReleaseVersion:.=" & (if defined Minor set v=Revision) & set "!v!=%"

echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%
```

Further details at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690206/delims-more-then-1-character-as-delimiter/33110951#33110951).

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

You may read a full description of the split method [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429). However, this answer also use an `if defined Minor` command in order to change the variable name from "Minor" to "Revision" after Minor variable value was set; this point can be easily understood if you remove the `@echo off` command and review the trace output.

Although this method allows to define more than two variables with different names, it is somewhat cumbersome to insert a `& (if defined prevVar set v=newVar)` command for each additional variable. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=1.0.2.25"

set "v=Minor"
set "Major=%str:.=" & (if defined Minor set v=Revision) & (if defined Revision set v=Subrev) & set "!v!=%"

echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%, Subrev: %Subrev%
```

The splitting of a string in several *different* variables can the achieved in a better way with the aid of a subroutine:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

call :SplitString "1.0.2.35" Major Minor Revision Subrev
echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%, Subrev: %Subrev%

goto :EOF


:SplitString string varName ...

rem Get string in "str" variable
set "str=%~1"

rem Create "v" array with variable names
set i=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set "v[!i!]=%%a"
   set /A i+=1
)

rem Separate the string in individual variables
set "p=%%"
set i=1
set "!v[1]!=%str:.=" & set /A i+=1 & call set "!p!v[!i!]!p!=%"

exit /B
```

The split method used in this subroutine is explained with detail in [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429&p=41069&#p41069), but I copied here the relevant parts and modified they for this example:

---

Note that the `call set "!p!v[!i!]!p!=%"` part is a *nested replacement* that is executed with each one of the substrings of the original replacement. This way, this method is comprised of three stages:

- The original string is split in several parts via the first %str% expansion, for example: `call set "!p!v[!i!]!p!=1"`, `call set "!p!v[!i!]!p!=0"`, etc.
- Each part is processed using delayed expansion !variables! to assemble the final expression. This method allows to insert quotes and other special characters, like percent signs, in places that the original %expansion% can not handle. For example: `call set "%v[1]%=1"`, `call set "%v[2]%=0"`, etc.
- The final expression in each part is evaluated via the nested CALL command, for example: `set "Major=1"`, `set "Minor=0"`, etc.

---

**EDIT 2018/02/18:** *New method added*

I developed a new method that allows to assign values to different variables using just one line. This method is new in the sense that allows to split *two variables* in the same line/replacement:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=1.0.2.25"
set "vars=Major Minor Revision Subrev"

set "p=%%"
set "v=%vars: =" & set "s=!str:*.=!" & call set "!v!=!p!str:.!s!=!p!" & set "str=!s!" & set "v=%" & set "!v!=!s!"

echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%, Subrev: %Subrev%
```

**EDIT 2022/01/05:** *New simpler method added*

I developed a new method to achieve this split that is *simpler* in the sense that it does not introduce additional elements besides the variable names:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "str=1.0.2.25"

set "Major=%str:.=" & set /A "Minor=Revision, Revision=Subrev, Subrev=%"

echo Major: %Major%, Minor: %Minor%, Revision: %Revision%, Subrev: %Subrev%
```

In this example an even simpler `set /A` command is used. If the assigned values were not numeric, just change the single SET /A by three standard `set` commands.

Comment: Cool trick, but it could be useful to explain this technic, as it may not be obvious to everyone (I need some minutes)

Comment: I like the last method (2018-02-18), it's simple to use and the technic is awesome

Answer (score 3):

Not have enough reputation to comment. Posting an answer instead :)

There's a helpful resource: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html

```
SET _test=123456789abcdef0

::Skip 7 characters and then extract the next 5

 SET _result=%_test:~7,5%
 ECHO %_result%          =89abc
```

Use this approach to extract substrings from the string as you want.

**UPDATE:**

[Get position of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916913/how-i-get-the-position-of-a-character-from-a-string-in-batch)

As you get the dot position, you can use the above described approach to extract necessary parts from the input string.

Comment: How do I split a string using a "dot' as a delimiter