# Batch: count the number of digits in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to find a way to know the number of digits in variable. For now, I'm trying to use this code. In this example, %var% is the variable that I need to know the number of digits it has.

```
    set x=1
    set var=12345
    :LOOP
    set temp=%var:~0,%x%%
    if %temp%==%var% goto END
    set x=%x%+1
    goto LOOP
    :END
```

Theoretically, at the end of the code %x% would be the number of digits %var% has. However, it doesn't work. I found out the problem is at the 3rd line. I modified the code to diagnose:

```
    set x=1
    set var=12345
    :LOOP
    set temp=%var:~0,%x%%
    echo %temp%
    pause
    if %temp%==%var% goto END
    set x=%x%+1
    goto LOOP
    :END
```

The result echoed was:

```
    x%%
```

Can anyone pinpoint my mistake or give an alternative solution to determine the number of digits in a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "number of digits?" Will your test strings be all-digits? will there be a size limit? Do you mean "distinct digits" (so 121212 has 2 distinct digits) or are you interested in the number of numerical characters (so 'hello123' would have 3?)

Comment: Yes, all variable would be numbers. 12345 would have 5 digits. There's no size limit.

Comment: I suggest you to review [Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45472269/778560)'s answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is

```
 set temp=%var:~0,%x%%
```

This does not work. The parser is not able to properly determine what percent sign belongs to what variable. You can enable delayed expansion and write it as

```
set "temp=!var:~0,%x%!"
```

For alternative versions, to handle any length string, any of the posted answers will work.

For a simpler solution, if you are sure the string is under 10 characters, then this is an alternative

```
set "x=0123456789%var%"
set "x=%x:~-10,1%"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a short solution, that only works for numeric variables:

```
set /a Log=1%var:~1%-%var:~1% -0
set /a Len=%Log:0=+1%
```

The variable `%Len%` will contain the number of digits in `%var%`.

### Explanation

The basic idea is to convert the first digit to `1`, and the rest of them (the 'trailing' digits) to `0`'s. Then we can use the string replacement function to replace all the `0`'s with `+1` giving us `1+1+1....` and evaluate the string as an arithmetic expression. This will give us the total number of digits.

The 'trailing' digits can be gotten using `%var:~1%` and we convert them to `0` by subtracting them from the variable itself: `45678 - 5678` gives `40000` etc. However, the above code subtracts them from `1%var:~1%` instead, in order to replace the first digit with `1` (i.e. `1` followed by the 'trailing' digits).

The reason for the extra  `-0` is in case `%var%` only has one digit, for example `7`. In that case, the expression `1%var:~1%-%var:~1%` would evaluate to `1-`  and the shell would complain: `Missing operand.` The  `-0` ensures that we always have a valid expression.

Now that we've converted the variable in to the proper form into `%Log%`, we can replace every occurrence of `0` with `+1`using `%Log:0=+1%` and evaluate the resulting expression using `set /a`, giving us our final result.

Comment: This method is fantastic! **`;)`** You may simplify it a little this way: `set /a Log=1%var%-var` and `set /a Len=%Log:0=+1% -1`

Comment: @Aacini Thanks! Feel free to edit it in at the end of the answer. I'll leave the original as is because I can't be bothered to modify the explanation, and because the `+0` has pedagogical value.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no build in function for string length, you can write your own function.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "myString=abcdef!%%^^()^!"
call :strlen result myString
echo %result%
goto :eof

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "s=!%~2!#"
    set "len=0"
    for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
        if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "s=!s:~%%P!"
        )
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

This function needs always 13 loops, instead of a simple strlen function which needs strlen-loops.
It handles all characters.

Source: [How do you get the string length in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: Okay... quite a long code, but definitely usable. Can anyone pinpoint my code's mistake?

Comment: It isn't much of a mistake its that doing this is surprising complicated. Look at @MCND Answer it shows you more about your code and how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to do this loop :

```
@Echo Off
Set /P VrStr=Enter your string :
:Loop
If "%VrStr%" EQU "" Goto EndLoop
Set VrStr=%VrStr:~0,-1%
Set /A VrLgr+=1
Goto Loop
:EndLoop
Echo Number of char: %VrLgr%
Pause
```

You can use this to :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /P $Tstring=Enter your string:
for /l %%a in (0,1,9000) do (set $t=!$Tstring:~%%a,1!&if not defined $t (echo [NB OF CHAR =] %%a&pause&exit /b))
pause
```