# I need to get the filename from a command in batch input loop

Tags: batch-file, arguments, substring

I'm making a prompt loop in a batch file

I'm trying to read the input for commands and arguments.

Currently, I check the first 4 letters for `open`, then I want to grab the next word which should be a filename to open.

I'm wanting to grab the text between spaces at index 1.

`open file.txt` -> `file.txt`

I need something like an inverse of mid-string

mid-string: `%input:~0,4%` - `open file.txt` -> `open`

I honestly need `%input:~5,-0%` to work! haha

`%input:~5,-1%` works... Why not with a `0` instead of `1`?

It's too bad batch has no way of getting a string's length.

I found something that would get a string's length:
[How do you get the string length in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file)

I tried it with the code:

```
call :strlen length input
echo %input:~5,length%
```

It always parsed weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
set "input=open file.txt"
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('echo/%input%') do (set "fileName=%%a")
echo/%fileName%
pause>nul
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo %input:~5%
```

Up to the end of the string if it is not indicated.

Answer (score 1):

a little variation to Rafaels answer (check first word for `open`):

```
@echo off
set "input=open file.txt"
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in ('echo/%input%') do ( if /i "%%a"=="open" set "fileName=%%b")
echo/%fileName%
pause>nul
```