# DOS command find space in filename starting from right

Tags: batch-file, dos

Is there a command that will return the position of a the first space found in a filename starting from the right?

Example:

"my filename.txt" would return 13
"my file name.txt" would return 9

Thanks

Comment: no, there is no such command. You will have to write a script for it.

Comment: DOS? Surely you mean cmd.exe, which has nothing whatsoever to do with DOS.

Comment: Yeah, I am old... cmd.exe

Comment: Simple in PowerShell (see answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
set "var=my filename.txt"
:: here call the function. returns "length"
CALL :mylength
ECHO Length is %length% ERRORLEVEL is %errorlevel%
GOTO :EOF

:mylength
setlocal
SET /a length=0
:mylenloop
IF "%var:~-1%" neq " " SET "var=%var:~0,-1%"&SET /a length+=1&GOTO mylenloop
endlocal&SET length=%length%
:: optional : set errorlevel to the length as well
EXIT /b %length%
```

This function returns the length of the string *after* the space. If you want to include the space, simply change `SET /a length=0` to `SET /a length=1`.

You don't say what to do if there are **no** spaces in the string, but this solution works where there is more than one space.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> $s = "test string 1"
PS C:\> $s.LastIndexOf(" ")
11
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct batch command, but it is not hard to compute. You can use find/replace to remove everything up through the first space. Then all you need do is compute the remaining length and add 1.

I recommend the [good performing :strlen function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1012053)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=my filename.txt"
set "test=!var:* =!"
call :strlen pos test 
set /a pos+=1
echo result=%pos%
exit /b

:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "s=!%~2!#"
set "len=0"
for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
  if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
    set /a "len+=%%P"
    set "s=!s:~%%P!"
  )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%len%"
exit /b
```