# Batch file decides that 4 > 39, How do I fix it?

Tags: batch-file

Note: The file Default.txt contains one line with these three characters:**1:X**

```
    @echo off
    set r=0
    :: For loop retrieves lines of text from the file Default.txt 
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a IN (Default.txt) DO (
    :: Each line is saved to a different variable.
    set _%%a=%%b
    set n=%%a
    )
    set ln=1
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    :process
    :: This loop processes all the lines in the text file.
    set r=0
    if "%n%" GTR "0" (
    :len
    :: This loop determines the length of each string.
    if not "!_%ln%:~%r%,1!"=="" (
    set /a r=%r%+1
    goto len
    )
    :space
    :: This loop adds spaces to each string so they will all be 39 characters in length.
    if "%r%" LEQ "39" (
    :: Note that there is a mandatory space at the end of the following line.
    set _%ln%=!_%ln%! 
    set /a r=%r%+1
    goto space
    )
    set /a n-=1
    set /a ln+=1
    goto process
    ) else (
    endlocal
    set _1=%_1%
    )
    echo %_1%]
    pause >nul
```

When the script is run however, instead of adding 38 spaces, it only adds 3.
By turning echo back on, I found the exact point where it exits the :space loop.

```
    C:\>if "1" LEQ "39" (
    set _1=!_1!
     set /a r=1+1
     goto space
    )

    C:\>if "2" LEQ "39" (
    set _1=!_1!
     set /a r=2+1
     goto space
    )

    C:\>if "3" LEQ "39" (
    set _1=!_1!
     set /a r=3+1
     goto space
    )
```

Up to this point, everything is working as it should.
Suddenly:

```
    C:\>if "4" LEQ "39" (
    set _1=!_1!
     set /a r=4+1
     goto space
    )
```

For some reason, 4 is suddenly greater than 39, and it moves on to the next section instead of incrementing the variable and looping again like it should.

```
    C:\>set /a n-=1

    C:\>set /a ln+=1

    C:\>goto process
```

And the program moves on and only 3 spaces are ever added to the variable.
I have no idea what the problem is and would be grateful for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  C:\>if 4 LEQ 39 (
set _1=!_1!
 set /a r=4+1
 goto space
)
```

Remove quotations and try that should work , quotes are normally used with strings.

Comment: Just to add some clarification - because quotes are being used, bash evaluates the strings lexicographically (similar to alphabetically), instead of numerically. In the same way that "A" < "B", "1" < "2", or when you have multiple characters, "aaaa" < "bbbb" and "11" < "20". When you have different lengths, it still evaluates alphabetically, so "111" < "20".

Answer (score 1):

When comparing numerics, don't enclose them in quotation marks.

> command: `if "4" leq "39" echo hi`
>   output: (empty line)
>
> command: `if 4 leq 39 echo hi`
>   output: `hi`

The reason for that is that "4" is alphabetically after "39", so `"4` is greater than `"3`.  When comparing using quotation marks, the comparison is alphabetic, not numeric as you intended.

You've got a few other problems with your script.  Don't put labels within parenthetical code blocks.  You need to find some other place to put `:len` and `:space` outside of the `if` statement where they currently live.  Strictly speaking, `::` is also label named `:`, not a substitute for `rem`.  When using `::` as a comment, avoid using it within parenthetical code blocks as well.  Use `rem` instead.  Also, indent your code to make it easier to ensure you've got the same number of `(` as `)`.  Let me ask you: which is more readable?

**option 1:**

```js
...
:space
:: This loop adds spaces to each string so they will all be 39 characters in length.
if "%r%" LEQ "39" (
:: Note that there is a mandatory space at the end of the following line.
set _%ln%=!_%ln%! 
set /a r=%r%+1
goto space
)
set /a n-=1
set /a ln+=1
goto process
) else (
endlocal
set _1=%_1%
)
echo %_1%]
pause >nul
```

The `else` is a continuation of the `if` statement above it, right?  **Wrong!**  Properly indented, you'd see that it's part of an `if` statement much higher in the script.

**option 2:**

```js
    rem This loop adds spaces to each string so they will all be 39 characters in length.

    if "%r%" LEQ "39" (
        rem Note that there is a mandatory space at the end of the following line.
        set _%ln%=!_%ln%! 
        set /a r=%r%+1
        goto space
    )

    set /a n-=1
    set /a ln+=1
    goto process

) else (
    endlocal
    set _1=%_1%
)
echo %_1%]
pause >nul
```

I'll never understand why some people insist on left-justifying every line of code they write.  It only makes things much more difficult to troubleshoot.

---

You know, there are more efficient ways to repeat characters.  Rather than looping, you could do variable substring extraction.

```js
set "spaces=                                                  "
set "39spaces=%spaces:~-39%"
```

If you want to get the length of a string, the fastest way I've found to do that is based on [jeb's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1683264):

```js
:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~2"=="" (set ret=0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~2"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
        set /a ret += %%I
        set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
goto :EOF
```

Example usage:

> command: `call :length len "The quick brown fox"`
>   command: `echo %len%`
>   output: `19`

Even if you're getting the length of a 2000 character line, that loop still counts the length in only 13 iterations, rather than potentially thousands.

Answer (score 0):

[Prudviraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31680791/2096401) answers why your original code doesn't work, but for an easier way of padding a string to 39 characters, you could try:

**Make39.bat**

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set "R=%1"
    set "R=%R%                                       "   REM append 39 spaces
    set "R=%R:~,39%"                                     REM take first 39 characters
    echo :123456789012345678901234567890123456789:
    echo :%R%:
```

which works as follows:

```
S:\>make39 abc
:123456789012345678901234567890123456789:
:abc                                    :

S:\>make39 "Quite a long string"
:123456789012345678901234567890123456789:
:Quite a long string                    :
```

Your comments seem to imply no string will initially be *longer* than 39 characters; you would have to get more inventive if this were possible (I would probably take the first 39 characters of the original `R` and see if that and `R` differ: if they did, the original would have been longer, so there would be no need to add padding).