# Variable doesn't get updated in the function of Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch script that will read the value in file version.property and perform a certain job my code is below

```
TITLE StartEODMaintenance
echo off
cls
set "Build=0"

call:FindString "MAINALGO"
IF /I "%Build%" == "MAINALGO" (
echo "start job on MainAlgo"
) else (
    call:FindString "DRSITEALGO"
    echo build value %Build%
    IF /I "%Build%" == "DRSITEALGO" (
        echo "start job on secondAlgo"
    ) else (
    echo "sth wrong"    
    )
)

:FindString
echo funtioninput %~1
find /I /C "%~1" version.property
if %errorlevel%==1 (
echo "errorlevel 1"
set "Build=0"
)
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo "errorlevel 0" 
set "Build=%~1"
echo build value in function %Build%
)
:end
```

The content in version.property is below

```
DRSITEALGO
```

The problem is I found that when the program is executed it looks like the below line work incorrectly. The variable Build is not set to the value in "%~1"

```
set "Build=%~1"
```

I got the below as output

```
funtioninput MAINALGO

---------- VERSION.PROPERTY: 0
"errorlevel 1"
funtioninput DRSITEALGO   ---> the %~1 show the correct value, DRSITEALGO   

---------- VERSION.PROPERTY: 1    
"errorlevel 0"
build value in function 0   ---> here is wrong! the Build variable somehow didn't get updated, it suppose to be DRSITEALGO   
build value 0
"sth wrong"
```

Not sure that I have to set anything to make it works??

Comment: Try adding `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of the file

Comment: ...and expand variables inside the loops with `!!` rather than `%%`; consult also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%variables%` are expanded when the command is parsed and the command `if` followed by a block is parsed *at once*. So when you set a variable in the block, its following usage (in `echo` here) has been expanded already and it results in showing the value that was valid before entering the block!

You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to read variable values at the moment when they are used, not parsed. First, issue the command:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

Then refer to the variables modified earlier within the same block as `!variable!`.

```
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo "errorlevel 0" 
set "Build=%~1"
echo build value in function !Build!
)
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that he's ever trying to retrieve a value modified within a code block.  I don't think premature expansion is the problem.  **Edit:** Well, he does `echo build value in function %Build%`, but that would only result in a cosmetic problem.  That's easily fixed by changing `%Build%` to `%~1`.

Comment: Adding change to  !Build! inside the :FindString make the program echo the correct value, how about if I want to access the Build variable in the main section, do I have to use the syntax !Build! all the time?

Comment: @tune No, after you exit the block, you can use `%variable%` again. And pay attention to nested blocks, the _most outer one_ must be finished. You can check it by adding another `echo` command. And as @rojo suggests, you should place an `exit /b` command before the `:FindString` definition.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that your script continues to `:FindString` as part of the main runtime.  On line 6 you `call :FindString "MAINALGO"`, then you've got an `IF` code block.  After that code block, you should `exit /b` or `goto :EOF` or something to halt execution of the main runtime, but you don't.  Instead, your script continues to `:FindString` a second unintended time, sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` by `find /I /C "" version.property`, and continues to the end.

Something else you might find interesting is [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution).  Instead of

```js
find /I /C "%~1" version.property
if %errorlevel%==1 (
echo "errorlevel 1"
set "Build=0"
)
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo "errorlevel 0" 
set "Build=%~1"
echo build value in function %Build%
)
```

... or ...

```js
find /I "%~1" version.property
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo "errorlevel 1"
    set "Build=0"
) else (
    echo "errorlevel 0" 
    set "Build=%~1"
    echo build value in function %Build%
)
```

... you could condense your code a bit like this:

```js
find /I "%~1" version.property && (
    echo "errorlevel 0" 
    set "Build=%~1"
    echo build value in function %Build%
) || (
    echo "errorlevel 1"
    set "Build=0"
)
```

I also recommend that you avoid being lazy with your indenting and formatting.  While your code isn't [nearly as bad as it could be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31680385/1683264), it would still be a little easier to see what's going on in `:FindString` if you indent your code blocks.

Anyway, see whether you have better luck with this:

```js
TITLE StartEODMaintenance
echo off
cls
set "Build=0"

call :FindString "MAINALGO"

IF /I "%Build%"=="MAINALGO" (
    echo "start job on MainAlgo"
) else (
    call :FindString "DRSITEALGO"
    echo build value %Build%
    IF /I "%Build%"=="DRSITEALGO" (
        echo "start job on secondAlgo"
    ) else (
        echo "sth wrong"
        rem // exit non-zero
        exit /b 1
    )
)

exit /b 0
rem // end main runtime / begin script functions

:FindString
find /I "%~1" version.property && (
    echo "errorlevel 0" 
    set "Build=%~1"
    echo build value in function %~1
) || (
    echo "errorlevel 1"
    set "Build=0"
)
```

Comment: thx, you comment is very appreciate, indeed I am very new with batch programming