# Assignment inside a if block is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I need to read a data from registry, add 1 to it and then rewrite the data back in registry

```
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "subcounter"') do set "subcounter=%%b"

if %subcounter% EQU 6 (
    set /a counter=%counter%+1
    echo increasing value for counter %counter% >> abc.log
    reg add HKLM\Software\Looptest /f /v counter /t REG_SZ /d %counter%
    pause
)
```

But,the problem in this code is that, it does not increase the data of COUNTER. Any explanation ?

Thanks !

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Also set `/a` not set `\a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get updated in the function of Batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832215/variable-doesnt-get-updated-in-the-function-of-batch-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically...

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "subcounter"') do set "counter=%%b"

if %counter% EQU 6 (
    set /a counter+=1
    echo increasing value for counter !counter! >> abc.log
    reg add HKLM\Software\Looptest /f /v counter /t REG_SZ /d !counter!
)
```

Alternatively, use `CALL`, and double `%%`.

```
@echo off
FOR /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Looptest" /v "subcounter"') do set "counter=%%b"

if %counter% EQU 6 (
    set /a counter+=1
    call echo increasing value for counter %%counter%% >> abc.log
    call reg add HKLM\Software\Looptest /f /v counter /t REG_SZ /d %%counter%%
)
```