# Batch SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion and Math problems

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, math, cmd

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set/a Number1=3+9
12
C:\WINDOWS\system32>if !Number1!==9+3 (echo Good) else (echo Bad)
Bad
C:\WINDOWS\system32>if !Number1!==3+9 (echo Good) else (echo Bad)
Bad
C:\WINDOWS\system32>set/a i=9+3
12
C:\WINDOWS\system32>if !Number1!==%i% (echo Good) else (echo Bad)
Bad
```

I expected to see the last results (and maybe some others) to show `Good` as a result but did not! I think this is because it is a error with the `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` but I need that in my code. So how do I get my expected result with `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. Thanks for any help provided =)

Comment: Are you typing all those lines in command prompt?? in that case, `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` has no effect, and the `!!` expansion will therefore not work; you need to open a new `cmd` instance to enable delayed expansion: `cmd /V:ON`

Comment: In addition, you should use comparison operator `EQU` for numerical operations, because `==` forces *string* comparison...

Comment: Yes I typed all those in command prompt. And yes, after I tried it in a batch file, it worked! I'm also gonna try using EQU. Thanks :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

`setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` only works within batch files (see also `setlocal /?`), it has no effect when being typed into command prompt; therefore the `!!` expansion does not work.

To use delayed expansion in command prompt, you need to open a new `cmd` instance:

```
cmd /V:ON
```

---

You cannot do arithmetics in the comparison expressions of the `if` statement directly, you need to do all the calculations in advance.
In addition, you should use the comparison operator `EQU` for numeric operations, because `==` forces string comparison:

```
set /A Number1=3+9
set /A i=9+3
if !Number1! EQU %i% (echo Good) else (echo Bad)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "`==` forces string comparison"? The numeric comparison have only sense with greater/less comparisons. If two values are equal/different, does not matter if they are taken as numbers or strings!

Comment: I agree, `==` and `EQU` give the same result; I just wanted to point out that they do not behave exactly the same...

Comment: Excuse me. If `==` and `EQU` do not behave exactly the same, what is exactly the difference? Could you post any code that show this difference?

Comment: @Aacini, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31680385/5047996) is an example; and this one: `if 1 EQU 01` evaluates to True, where `if 1==01` is False...

Comment: Ok. Although this involves a different concept (because both values are _different based numbers_ that will never be generated by the same operations), I must admit you are right: `if 18 equ 0x12 echo True`