# Unable to append to environment variable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to append four directories to %pythonpath%.
The directories are:

1. C:\src\tensorflow\models\research
2. C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection
3. ..\utils
4. ..\mail

When user is User42, %pythonpath% is always set to:

**;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection;..\utils;..\mail**

Why is the first path ignored/overwritten?

```
@echo off
if "%username%"=="User42" (
    set pythonpath=%pythonpath%;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research
    set pythonpath=%pythonpath%;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection
) else (
    :: Other path
)

:: This is common to all users
set pythonpath=%pythonpath%;..\utils;..\mail
echo %pythonpath%
```

Comment: Use delayedexpansion. Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198978/batch-setlocal-enabledelayedexpansion-and-math-problems also https://superuser.com/questions/78496/ https://superuser.com/questions/330118/ where it is ontopic unlike here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows batch SET inside IF not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102422/windows-batch-set-inside-if-not-working)

Comment: Just update the variable in one shot: `set pythonpath=%pythonpath%;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection`, so there is no need for delayed expansion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows command processor replaces all environment variable references with syntax `%VariableName%` in a command block starting with `(` and ending with matching `)` during parsing phase of the next command line to execute on which a command block begins. In this case this means **all** `%pythonpath%` in both branches of the **IF** condition are substituted already by the current value of environment variable `pythonpath` before the **IF** condition is executed at all. This behavior can be seen by running the batch file without `@echo off` from within a command prompt window as in this case Windows command processor outputs the command lines after being parsed before execution.

The solution is using [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as also explained by help of command **SET** output on running in a command prompt window `set /?` on an **IF** and a **FOR** example, or avoiding the definition or modification of an environment variable and referencing it once again in same command block.

Here is a solution which works without usage of delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
set "Separator="
if defined pythonpath if not "%pythonpath:~-1%" == ";" set "Separator=;"
if /I "%username%" == "User42" (
    set "pythonpath=%pythonpath%%Separator%C:\src\tensorflow\models\research;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection"
) else (
    rem Other path is added here to environment variable pythonpath.
)

rem This is common to all users. Variable pythonpath is defined definitely now.
for %%I in ("%CD%") do set "ParentPath=%%~dpI"
set "pythonpath=%pythonpath%;%ParentPath%utils;%ParentPath%mail"
echo %pythonpath%
```

It additionally makes sure there is not `;;` in value of `pythonpath` in case of there is already a semicolon at end. And it makes sure `pythonpath` is not defined with a `;` at beginning if this environment variable does not exist at all before first **IF** condition.

Further there are no relative paths added to `pythonpath` because of determining absolute path for `..\utils` and `..\mails` before appending them to `pythonpath`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

BTW: Invalid labels `::` as comments should not be used in command blocks. That can result in undefined behavior on execution. It is safer to use command **REM** for comments.

Answer (score 1):

`%pythonpath%` used twice between parentheses will be evaluated on read before execution begins.
This is why `%pythonpath%` has the same value on the 2nd `set`.

You can use `call set` to force evaluation on the variable with doubled `%`s.
This has a similar effect to `enabledelayedexpansion` seen in `setlocal /?`
and `if /?`.

```
@echo off
if "%username%"=="User42" (
    set "pythonpath=%pythonpath%;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research"
    call set "pythonpath=%%pythonpath%%;C:\src\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection"
) else (
    :: Other path
)

:: This is common to all users
set "pythonpath=%pythonpath%;..\utils;..\mail"
echo %pythonpath%
```