# count length of filenames in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

my problem is I want to count the length of multiple filenames and save this numbers into a file.

My approach is this:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
    set Datei=%%~ni
    call :strLen Datei strlen

    :strLen
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    :strLen_Loop
    if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1 & goto :strLen_Loop
    (endlocal & set %2=%len%)

    echo.%strlen%>> tmp
)
```

The problem here is it only works for the first filename and after that it is stuck and does not go on to the next filename.

Comment: `goto` and labels don't work inside the loop. Move the corresponding parts of code outside the loop.

Comment: oh yeah thank u very much it works now!

Comment: You may post the fixed code and the remark why it wasn't working as an answer then.

Comment: No, not as a comment (delete it), but as an answer.

Comment: `>lengths.tmp (for %# in (*.txt) do @echo %#^|%~z#)` (in a batch, use `%%#` and `%%~z#`)

Comment: To get the length of a string you might be interested in this excellent effort: [How do you get the string length in a batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/5047996)

Comment: @JosefZ, you are generating a list of file _sizes_, but not a list of _lengths of file paths_...

Answer (score 3):

Just for another alternative of a one-line command:

```
for %# in (*.txt) do @for /F "delims=:" %G in ('(echo "%~f#"^&echo(^)^|findstr /O "^"') do @if %~G NEQ 0 ( <^NUL set /p "dummy=%~f#|%~z#|"&set /a %~G-5&echo()
```

or the same in a bit more readable form:

```
for %# in (*.txt) ^
do @for /F "delims=:" %G in ('(echo "%~f#"^&echo(^)^|findstr /O "^"') ^
do @if %~G NEQ 0 ( <^NUL set /p "dummy=%~f#|%~z#|"&set /a %~G-5&echo()
```

Unfortunately, unlike the `cmd` *shell*, `set` command does not display its result in a *batch script*. Therefore, we need to set a string length to an environment variable and then `echo` its value with [delayed expansion enabled](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem file lengths:
rem for %%A in (*.txt) do echo Name:%%A, Length: %%~zA
rem full path lengths:
for %%# in (*.txt) do (
  for /F "delims=:" %%G in ('(echo "%%~f#"^&echo(^)^|findstr /O "^"') do (
    if %%~G NEQ 0 (
      set /a "length=%%~G-5"
      rem echo(%%~f#^|%%~z#^|!length!
      echo(%%~f#^|!length!
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Very well piece of code, thank you. here a variant with filename.ext only (remove every x if you want filename only) `for %# in (*.txt) do @for /F "delims=:" %G in ('(echo "%~nx#"^&echo(^)^|findstr /O "^"') do @if %~nG NEQ 0 ( <^NUL set /p "dummy=%~nx#|"&set /a %~G-5&echo()
`

Answer (score 2):

Just for another alternative, `findstr` can output the offset of each matching line. Using it over the `dir` output and substracting the offset of the previous line from the current one (and the CRLF at the end of the line), we get the length of the previous line / file name

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "lastOffset=0"
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('(dir /b *.txt ^& echo(^) ^| findstr /o "^"') do (
        if %%a gtr 0 (
            set /a "size=%%a - lastOffset - 2"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            echo(!fileName! !size!
            endlocal
        )
        set "lastOffset=%%a"
        set "fileName=%%b"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

[A slightly modified how to do count length of file name.](https://superuser.com/a/503135)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
    for  /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir *.txt /B /S /A:-D ^| findstr /IV "_output.txt"') do (
        set "name=%%~nA" 
        @echo "!name!">"%TMP%\_Temp.txt"

        for %%I in ("%TMP%\_Temp.txt") do ( 
            set /a "length=%%~zI"
            set /a length-=4
            @echo !length!:'!name!'
        )
    )
)> _output.txt 2>&1
del "%TMP%\_Temp.txt"
MORE /C /P _output.txt
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

well the solution was coming from you i just moved the parts out of the loop. the code is this:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
set Datei=%%~ni
call :strLen Datei strlen
)

:strLen
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:strLen_Loop
if not "!%1:~%len%!"=="" set /A len+=1
goto :strLen_Loop

(endlocal & set %2=%len%)
echo.%strlen%>> tmp
```

Comment: The script does not stop of itself.