# Substring length in text file using Batch

Tags: batch-file, text

In input, I have a text file which contains numbers separated with a comma.

```
list.txt
111221,345,332133,66,5555, and so
```

I want to check the length of each string between the "," delimiter, in order to successively display the length of each word.

For example:

```
111221 is 6 characters long
345 is 3 characters long
332133 is 6 characters long
66 is 2 characters long
...
```

For this, I've written this code but it displays only the first word and the length is always "0". Without the for loop, it works fine for a single chain. Has anyone an idea to fix this?
Thank you.

```
@echo off                   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /f "delims=," %%a in ('type list.txt') do (
set string=%%a
set temp_str=%string%
set str_len=0

:loop
if defined temp_str (

set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
set /a str_len+=1
goto:loop )

echo !string! is !str_len! characters long
)

pause
endlocal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off                   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('type q35202446.txt') do (
 for %%a in (%%f) do (
  set "string=%%a"
  set "temp_str=!string!"
  set str_len=0
  CALL :loop
  echo !string! is !str_len! characters long
 )
)

GOTO :eof

:loop
if defined temp_str (
 set temp_str=%temp_str:~1%
 set /a str_len+=1
 GOTO loop )

GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q35202446.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Your problems are :

for /f ... reads a line at a time, so `delims=,` would provide you with just the first token in the line. Next iteration would read the next line (if it existed)

Putting the entire line (`"delims="`) into `%%f` allows you to use the default function of `,` (along with space, semicolon and tab) - a separator. The `for ... %%a...` sees a simple list of elements separated by commas.

You must use `!string!` to access the run-time value of `string` (with *delayedexpansion* invoked.) `%string%` will deliver the **parse-time** value of `string`  which will be empty, hence reporting length 0.

Note the use of quotes in the string-assignment. That syntax ensures trailing spaces are not included in the string assigned.

A label terminates a "block" (parenthesised series of statements) so I've moved the length-calculator to a subroutine.

Your `echo` was correctly using `!var!` to access the run-time value of the variables.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you for you help and for all the explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `for /f` to read line-by-line, then an inner `for` to tokenize each line on the commas.  Something like this:

```js
@echo off                   
setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("list.txt") do (
    for %%t in (%%a) do (
        call :length len %%t
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo %%t is !len! characters long.
        endlocal
    )
)

goto :EOF

:length <return_var> <string>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%~2"=="" (set ret=0) else set ret=1
set "tmpstr=%~2"
for %%I in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
    if not "!tmpstr:~%%I,1!"=="" (
        set /a ret += %%I
        set "tmpstr=!tmpstr:~%%I!"
    )
)
endlocal & set "%~1=%ret%"
goto :EOF
```

Credit: the `:length` function is [based on jeb's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1683264).  It's much more efficient than a `goto` loop.