# .bat measure file path length and put it in a .txt-file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a .bat file that will run through all files in a given folder, measure the length of the file+path and if its longer than eg. 50 characters the file and path are written into a .txt-file.

I'm pretty much a n00b, so not to advanced, and somewhat well explained ;).

im writing into a file with

echo %File% > filer.txt

Where File should contain the file name and path.

Edit:
Im sorry, I was perhaps a bit unclear in my description of the task it should preform. What I ment was, loop trough files and subfolders of a given folder. and return in the document the files with a path longer than 50 including Drive and Filetype.

Comment: Oh god, if there is one thing batch isn't good at, it's measuring string length. I think your `not to advanced` is a terrible condition for this.

Comment: Does path+file include the drive, so `C:\path\somefile`, or `path\somefile`? And does it contain the extension?

Comment: check this [post by dbenham](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6478#p6478)

Comment: @npocmaka although it uses temporary files, I really like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8566001/5022761) solution, mostly because it's single line.

Answer (score 2):

As Dennis already noted, batch has no built-in solution for getting the lenght of the path. But if you only want to know, if a string is larger than `n`, just check, if there is a character at the `n+1` position:

```
if "%string:~51,1%" neq "" echo %string% is longer than 50 characters
```

Much faster than counting characters.

Combined with Dennis' logic:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  for %%g in ("*") do (
    set "File=%%~dpnxg"
    if "!File:~51,1!" neq "" echo !File!
  )
)>filer.txt
```

I put the whole `for` loop into another block to redirect only once to the output-file. this is much faster (`>>` would open the file, write one line and close the file, just to open it again etc...)

Comment: Why didn't I think of this. *silently judges himself*

Comment: Im sorry, I was perhaps a bit unclear in my description of the task it should preform. What I ment was, loop trough files and subfolders of a given folder. and return in the document the files with a path longer than 50 including Drive and Filetype.

Comment: just use the `for`parameter `/R`. See `for /?` for details.

Comment: thanks I got it to work after Lunch, the code properly just needed a brake from me (se my answer to Dennis;)
I'm a bit unsesure on the  'code !File:~51,1!" neq ' well I can guess moste of the meaning but I would like the more detailed form.

Comment: `%var:~n,m%` extracts a substring starting at character `n` with length `m` (now, that I think about it, `n` starts with zero, so it should be `50` instead of `51`). There is an example in `set /?`.

Comment: okay so just to be sure I understand it correctly
for all files (%%g) in folder(
set file=file including path
If place 52 (51+1) is not "" write file
into file.txt

in the !File! what is the ! for?

Comment: @SusanneKahl the `!` is used instead of `%` when using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%g in ("*") do (
set "File=%%~dpnxg"
>x echo !File!&for %%? in (x) do set /a strlength=%%~z? - 2&del x
if !strlength! gtr 50 echo !File! >> filer.txt
)
```

This loops through all files in the current folder, and puts their drive, path, name and extension in the variable `%File%`. It then writes `%File%` to a temporary file x, and gets the stringlength from that, and deletes x. If the string length is greater than 50 it writes the name of the file to `filer.txt`.

You need the [`delayed expansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) to work with variables inside loops.

Note, this code currently uses drive, path, filename and extension. Change the line `set "File=%%~dpnxg"` to change this behaviour (`[d]rive, [p]ath, [n]ame, e[x]tension`, the `g` is necesary)

Comment: Fails if there is a _folder_ named `x` in the current directory: `Access denied` and then `4094d:\bat\x\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?`

Comment: Im sorry, I was perhaps a bit unclear in my description of the task it should preform. What I ment was, loop trough files and subfolders of a given folder. and return in the document the files with a path longer than 50 including Drive and Filetype.

Comment: @SusanneKahl If it is supposed to loop through all files, even the ones in subfolders, you need to replace `for %%g in (` with `for /r %%g in (`, which also applies to @Stephan's answer

Comment: I can only get the change to work on your code not on Stephans  unfortunately. 
Can I get a short Introduction on what the lines do? now I got it to work, but dont know how ;)

Comment: And Yes I also have the Access Denied on folder X but only in some (bigger) folders.