# Check of the value set in an array (batch file in windows)

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file

I need your help for a batch file that I am trying to develop in a windows environment.

I have a string that contains a set of parameters split up by a hyphen like this:

```
     rossi-mario-rome-01031998
```

I need to check if the length of each of these 3 parameters doesn't exceed the maximum value defined in an array like this:

```
     set /a arraylen[1]=30
     set /a arraylen[2]=30
     set /a arraylen[3]=20
     set /a arraylen[4]=8
```

In case of the parameter's length exceeds the value defined in the array, a variable should be set to 1 and the script should be ended.

Please, can you help to develop such a script?

Comment: We can help you to develop the script, supposing you share what you have already; but we are not going to do your work for free. Please read the help: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [hint](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525639/bat-messure-file-path-length-and-put-it-in-a-txt-file)

Comment: [strlen](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6478)

Comment: @npocmaka as this is about **maximum** string length rather that string length in general I feel like the answer given by Stephan [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37526214/5022761) is less complicated.