# Creating input subfolder structure inside output folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that:

1. read input files from a folder
2. elaborate them
3. store output files in another folder

Example code:

```
set pathTmp=D:\a\b\c
set pathIn=%pathTmp%\in
set pathOut=%pathTmp%\out

for /f %%i in ('dir /b %pathIn%') do ( 
    java XXX.jar %pathIn%\%%i >> %pathOut%\%%i
)
```

Now I'd like to modify it to read files from all subfolders of `pathIn` and put the output file in the same subfolder **but** under `pathOut`.

*Example*: if input file is in `pathIn\zzz`, the output file must be in `pathOut\zzz`.

How can I recreate the input subfolder structure inside output folder?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `xcopy` together with the `/L` switch (to list files that would be copied) to retrieve the relative paths. For this to work, you need to change to the directory `%pathIn%` first and specify a relative source path (for this purpose, the commands `pushd` and `popd` can be used).

For example, when the current working directory is `D:\a\b\c\in` and its content is...:

> ```
> D:\a\b\c\in
>          |   data.bin
>          +---subdir1
>          |       sample.txt
>          |       sample.xml
>          \---subdir2
>                  anything.txt
> ```

...the command line `xcopy /L /I /S /E "." "D:\a\b\c\out"` would return:

> ```
> .\data.bin
> .\subdir1\sample.txt
> .\subdir1\sample.xml
> .\subdir2\anything.txt
> 3 File(s)
> ```

As you can see there are paths relative to the current directory. To get rid of the summary line `3 File(s)`, the `find ".\"` command line is used to return only those lines containing `.\`.

So here is the modified script:

```
set "pathTmp=D:\a\b\c"
set "pathIn=%pathTmp%\in"
set "pathOut=%pathTmp%\out"

pushd "%pathIn%"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('xcopy /L /I /S /E "." "%pathOut%" ^| find ".\"') do (
    md "%pathOut%\%%I\.." > nul 2>&1
    java "XXX.jar" "%%I" > "%pathOut%\%%I"
)
popd
```

Additionally, I placed `md "%pathOut%\%%I\.." > nul 2>&1` before the `java` command line so that the directory is created in advance, not sure if this is needed though. The redirection `> nul 2>&1` avoids any output, including error messages, to be displayed.

I put quotation marks around all paths in order to avoid trouble with white-spaces or any special characters in them. I also quoted the assignment expressions in the `set` command lines.

You need to specify the option string `"delims="` in the `for /F` command line, because the default options `tokens=1` and `delims=`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> would split your paths unintentionally at the first white-space.

Note that the redirection operator `>>` means to *append* to a file if it already exists. To overwrite, use the `>` operator (which I used).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
@setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
set pathTmp=D:\a\b\c
set pathIn=%pathTmp%\in
set pathOut=%pathTmp%\out

REM set inLength=ADD FUNCTION TO CALCULATE LENGTH OF PATHIN 

for /f %%i in ('dir /b /s %pathIn%') do ( 
    set var=%%i 
    java XXX.jar %%i >> %pathOut%\!var:~%inLength%!
)
```

This will strip the length of the `pathIn` directory from the absolute path leaving only the relative path. Then it appends the relative path onto the `pathOut` var

You would need to find or write a function to get the length of the the pathIn string. Check out some solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file).