# Usage of # with SET in batch programs

Tags: batch-file, window

I was searching for a way to get the length of a string in batch. So I read the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/6635287) from jeb which contains some mysterios signs I dont't get.

He uses the pound sign (#) in the function `strlen` when retrieving the input string:

```
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
[...]
    set "s=!%~2!#"
[...]
)
```

Can someone explain what the pound sign means?
As far as I understand the `!%~2!` gives the second parameter from the call. But what is the `#` used for and why is the expression after `SET` enclosed in `"`?

Comment: It is best practice to enclose the `SET` command with quotes.  It preserves special characters and prevents any trailing spaces you might not see at the end of the command. Why not put a comment below Jeb's answer to ask him the purpose instead of asking your question.  He comes here often and will probably answer you within the day.

Comment: Following a `:label` and a space  can be any information - it is ignored. Here it denotes what arguments the subroutine/function expects: `<resultVar> <stringVar>`  both by refefernce. The appended `#` is IMO there to convert the zero based offset calculation to a length by adding one char.

Comment: `#` has no special meaning. It's just a character, like `a`. The `set` command just appends that character to a given string (probably for the reason, LotPings mentioned).

Comment: `dostips` has a related [:strlen function](https://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.strLen) (with reversed arguments) I don't know which one is more efficient/faster.

Comment: @LotPings, I believe Jeb's is faster if my memory serves me.  I know it was discussed on DosTips some years ago.

Comment: Dbenham did an in depth speed test of all the common algorithms used on [SS64](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6478#p6478)

Comment: @Squashman The difference between the binary  variants seems neglible - but that the tempfile approach is best - is hmm.. disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the hash character `#` in the strlen function to solve two problems.

Splitting a variable with the `:~n,m` snytax fails for empty(undefined) variables, appending a character prevents that problem.

And the result of the algorithm is the string length minus one of the `s` variable, by appending a character compensate the result.

Why I used the hash?
The only reason I can remember is to use a character without any special batch  functionality and it is good visible.