# How to find and replace a number in a file and increment it?

Tags: batch-file

I have 5000 same files and I need to update numeric value in its content and increment it. Below is the batch script I use to find and replace a number in a certain file called `BULK_1.txt`.

I am not sure on how to increment the value after running search and replace.

```
@echo off 
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set search=01118596270001
set replace=01118596270002

set "textFile=BULK_1.txt"
set "rootDir=C:\Batch"

for %%j in ("%rootDir%\%textFile%") do (
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%%~j" ^& break ^> "%%~j"') do (
        set "line=%%i"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
        >>"%%~j" echo(!line!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

The result should be like below. The last 4 digits should be updated from 0001 to 5000 for each file

Content of the `BULK_1.txt`:

```
DMAIN            Test_data        01118596270001
DDOC_DATA        Test_docdata     01118596270001
```

Content of the `BULK_2`:

```
DMAIN            Test_data        01118596270002
DDOC_DATA        Test_docdata     01118596270002
```

Content of the `BULK_3`:

```
DMAIN            Test_data        01118596270003
DDOC_DATA        Test_docdata     01118596270003
```

Comment: increment would be `set /a cnt+=1` where the `cnt` variable would need to increase your initial value. see `set /?` from cmdline for help. but it does not seem as if you want to increment, it seems you want to use a value from the filename in the value itself, can you clarify? Will the last value always be the same as the end numeric value of the file name?

Comment: I'd reorder the elements in your question, situation as is, desired state and then your try to solve and what didn't work as expected. See [ask]

Comment: And time to accept an answer I think...

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements you may need:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /L %%A IN (1 1 5000) do (
    set num_processed=%%A
    call:find_len num_processed
    if !len! EQU 1 (set num_%%A=0111859627000%%A)
    if !len! EQU 2 (set num_%%A=011185962700%%A)
    if !len! EQU 3 (set num_%%A=01118596270%%A)
    if !len! EQU 4 (set num_%%A=0111859627%%A)
)

for /L %%A IN (1 1 5000) do (
    for /L %%B IN (1 1 2) do (
        if %%B EQU 1 (
            echo DMAIN            Test_data        !num_%%A!>BULK_%%A.txt
        ) else (
            echo DDOC_DATA        Test_docdata     !num_%%A!>>BULK_%%A.txt
        )
    )
)

:find_len
set "s=!%~1!#"
set "len=0"
for %%P in (4 2 1) do (
    if "!s:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "s=!s:~%%P!"
    )
)
```

My code uses the way that @jeb has suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5837418) slightly edited.

- First, we make a loop to count from 1 to 5000.

  - We want to count the length of each of these numbers. `call`ing the `find_len` subroutine does this.
  - `If` the string length of the variable is 1, then it must be `0001`. The number in front is the same in all cases.
  - `If` the string length of the variable is 2, then it must be `0010`. The number in front is the same in all cases.
  - `If` the string length of the variable is 3, then it must be `0100`. The number in front is the same in all cases.
  - `If` the string length of the variable is 4, then it must be `1000`. The number in front is the same in all cases.

*Note: If we tried something similar to `set /a 0000+1` the result would be `1`. That is why all of these complicates!*.

In all cases, the variable names will be `num_numberCurrentlyProcessed`.

- Now another loop, actually the same as before. It will loop 5000 times and will create 5000 files in the format `BULK_num.txt`.

  - Inside this loop, another loop is required from 1 to 2, as each file must have 2 lines.
  - `If` we are in line 1, we `echo` the specific text specified by OP.
  - `If` we are in line 1, we `echo` again the specific text specified by OP.

Answer (score 0):

"I have 5000 same files" - it's a lot faster to write them from scratch than to edit each of them:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "Hdr=DMAIN            Test_data        0111859627"
set "Dta=DDOC_DATA        Test_docdata     0111859627"

for /l %%a in (1,1,5000) do (
  set "num=0000%%a"     REM prepend some zeros
  set "num=!num:~-4!"   REM take last four chars
  >Bulk_%%a.txt (
    echo %Hdr%!num!
    echo %Dta%!num!
  )
)
```