# Windows (cmd) batch - usage of enclosing brackets in a subroutine

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax

I have often seen the schematic of parenthesis `( ... )` in a `:LABEL` .

I read up on parentheses/brackets, but I don't quite understand how to interpret this in a subroutine.

( e.g. https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html )

**Using variables within parentheses**
*The CMD shell will expand [read into memory] all the variables at the beginning of a code block and use those values even if the variable’s value is changed within the code block. Turning on DelayedExpansion will force the shell to read variables at the start of every line.*

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a specific description for a call or subroutine on the internet.

( e.g. https://ss64.com/nt/call.html, https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html )

I would like to know if it is *only* a code style (e.g. for readability), which is my current guess.

A quick example:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

CALL :ShortLabel
CALL :LongLabel
GOTO :EndOfBatch

:ShortLabel
ECHO I'm called "%~0" .
EXIT /B

:LongLabel
(
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" , because I have two extra lines.
   EXIT /B
)

:EndOfBatch
PAUSE
EXIT /B
```

If not, I would appreciate a brief explanation.

**Update:**

Since my previous "time measure" was garbage, here is a better version (I hope). The first call is just copy paste out of the brackets of the second:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM *** This string has the maximum length of 8191
set "str=."
FOR /L %%n in (1 1 13) DO SET "str=!str:~-4000!!str:~-4000!"
(set^ string=!str!!str:~-191!)

SET /A Loops=3000

TITLE A - StrLenNoLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

TITLE A - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE A - StrLenLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

TITLE A - StrLenLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

REM Invert order

TITLE B - StrLenLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE B - StrLenLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

TITLE B - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE B - StrLenNoLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

TITLE Results
ECHO.

ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocal            A :  !StrLenLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA!
ECHO.

CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocal            B :  !StrLenLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB!
ECHO.


GOTO :EndOfBatch

REM https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1378342
REM The original "function" is missing the /A for a number twice, which is wrong in my opinion. It seems to speed up the output.
REM I also added missing cosmetic double quotes for "set" to make it more accurate


:StrLenNoLocal
ECHO Loop %~3 / %Loops%
(SET^ tmp=!%~2!)
IF DEFINED tmp (
  SET /A "len=1"
  FOR %%P IN (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) DO (
     IF "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        SET /A "len+=%%P"
        SET "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
     )
  )
) ELSE (
  SET /A "len=0"
)
SET /A "%~1=!len!"
EXIT /B


:StrLenNoLocalBrackets
(
   ECHO Loop %~3 / %Loops%
   (SET^ tmp=!%~2!)
   IF DEFINED tmp (
      SET /A "len=1"
      FOR %%P IN (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) DO (
         IF "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
            SET /A "len+=%%P"
            SET "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
         )
      )
   ) ELSE (
      SET /A "len=0"
   )
   SET /A "%~1=!len!"
   EXIT /B
)


:StrLenLocal
echo Loop %~3 / %Loops% & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
if defined tmp (
  set /a "len=1"
  for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
     if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
     )
  )
) else (
    set /a "len=0"
)
endlocal & set /a "%~1=%len%" & exit /b


:StrLenLocalBrackets
(
   echo Loop %~3 / %Loops%
)
(
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
   if defined tmp (
      set /a "len=1"
      for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
         if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
         )
      )
   ) else (
        set /a "len=0"
   )
)
(
   endlocal
   set /a "%~1=%len%"
   exit /b
)



:TimeStamp
SET /A %~1=1%time:~-5,-3%%time:~-2%
EXIT /B

:MeasureTime
SET /A %~1=!%~3!-!%~2!
IF !%~1! LSS 0 SET /A %~1=6000+!%~1!
SET %~1=!%~1:~0,-2!.!%~1:~-2!sec
EXIT /B



:EndOfBatch
PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF
```

Output:

```
Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  17.57sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  15.06sec
Time StrLenLocal            A :  17.70sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  18.09sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191

Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  17.05sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  14.56sec
Time StrLenLocal            B :  17.39sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  17.84sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191
```

It looks like the `( ... )` version is faster...

As long as no one has any objections, my conclusion is:

I prefer code that has fewer lines, as long as it doesn't affect readability. *But* if the two brackets might make the script a little faster and it doesn't do any harm - why not? ;)

Comment: I've been writing batch scripts for 11 years and I've never seen this done. They _arguably_ don't hurt, but they're definitely there for purely aesthetic reasons. Traditionally the only time you see a set of parentheses that isn't attached to a `for` or an `if` is if you have a bunch of `echo`s that you want to all redirect to the same file and you only want to write one redirection operator.

Comment: @SomethingDark I've asked myself that a few times. When reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1378342 because the code is separated there twice...

Comment: That second set of code with the `endlocal` is doing that because it's slightly more readable than `endlocal&set "%~1=%len%"` and it takes advantage of the fact that the interpreter considers all of the commands inside of a set of parentheses to be a single command, but the first set doesn't seem to add any value; I get the same results regardless of whether they're there or not. That said, 2011 was a long time ago and it may have just been in style at the time.

Comment: @SomethingDark So if I would (nl) `(echo a echo b)` vs `echo a & echo b` vs (nl) `echo a echo b` it would be a little more cpu intensive...? (because it would interpret it at once?)

Comment: You should get the same performance in all three

Comment: Enclosing a code segment in parenthesis does NOT change the time in which _the whole code segment_ execute. The difference is that with no parenthesis, each line is executed sequentially (line by line), but if the segment is enclosed in parens, then all lines in the segment are executed much faster, because first all lines are parsed, and then all lines are executed at once. The only situation when this could be useful is in animation (games) programs

Comment: @Aacini What is the argument for not always doing it that way?

Comment: I said nothing about use or don't use parentheses to enclose code segments. However, if you use parentheses with no reason, you could be forced to use DelayedExpansion in places that don't need it before...

Comment: @Aacini Yes. I think I understand it now... more or less. After a few wrong turns. "The only situation when this could be useful is in animation..." was where I asked myself: what are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little "what if" …

- My measure make no sense
- I measure timeout / ping
- I run the whole thing inside brackets again
- I call a nested label inside brackets

thinking:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM *** This string has the maximum length of 8191
set "str=."
FOR /L %%n in (1 1 13) DO SET "str=!str:~-4000!!str:~-4000!"
(set^ string=!str!!str:~-191!)

SET /A Loops=3000


TITLE A - StrLenNoLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

TITLE A - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE A - StrLenLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

TITLE A - StrLenLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

REM Messure Timeout 5sec
TITLE Timeout 5sec
CALL :TimeStamp TimeoutStart
timeout /NOBREAK /T 5 >NUL
CALL :TimeStamp TimeoutEnd
CALL :MeasureTime TimeoutTime TimeoutStart TimeoutEnd

REM Ping...
TITLE Ping 5000
CALL :TimeStamp PingStart
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
CALL :TimeStamp PingEnd
CALL :MeasureTime PingTime PingStart PingEnd

REM Ping 50 * 100
TITLE PingOneHundredTimes
CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesStart
CALL :PingOneHundredTimes
CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesEnd

TITLE PingOneHundredTimesBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesBracketsStart
CALL :PingOneHundredTimesBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesBracketsEnd

CALL :MeasureTime PingOneHundredTimesTime PingOneHundredTimesStart PingOneHundredTimesEnd
CALL :MeasureTime PingOneHundredTimesBracketsTime PingOneHundredTimesBracketsStart PingOneHundredTimesBracketsEnd

REM Invert order

TITLE B - StrLenLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE B - StrLenLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

TITLE B - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

TITLE B - StrLenNoLocal
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB string %%a
CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

TITLE Results
ECHO.

REM "Empty" Timestamp Measure
CALL :TimeStamp TimestampStart
CALL :TimeStamp TimestampEnd
CALL :MeasureTime TimestampTime TimestampStart TimestampEnd

ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocal            A :  !StrLenLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA!
ECHO.

CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocal            B :  !StrLenLocalTime!
ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB!
ECHO.
ECHO "Empty" Timestamp Measure   :  !TimestampTime!
ECHO Timeout /T 5                :  !TimeoutTime!
ECHO ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000   :  !PingTime!
ECHO PingOneHundredTimes         :  !PingOneHundredTimesTime!
ECHO PingOneHundredTimesBrackets :  !PingOneHundredTimesBracketsTime!
ECHO.


SET AREYOUSURE=n
SET /P "AREYOUSURE=Do you like to start over again inside brackets (y/[n]) ? "
IF /I "!AREYOUSURE!" EQU "y" CALL :DoItAgain


REM Test if labels inside brackets still works...

REM Label inside a Label with brackets
ECHO.
CALL :LabelBrackets
CALL :LabelInsideLabelBrackets
ECHO.
REM Label inside a Label with brackets without Exit after LabelBracketsWOExit
CALL :LabelBracketsWOExit
CALL :LabelInsideLabelBracketsWOExit
ECHO.



GOTO :EndOfBatch

REM https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/1378342
REM The original "function" is missing the /A for a number twice, which is wrong in my opinion. It seems to speed up the output.
REM I also added missing cosmetic double quotes for "set" to make it more accurate


:StrLenNoLocal
ECHO Loop %~3 / %Loops%
(SET^ tmp=!%~2!)
IF DEFINED tmp (
  SET /A "len=1"
  FOR %%P IN (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) DO (
     IF "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        SET /A "len+=%%P"
        SET "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
     )
  )
) ELSE (
  SET /A "len=0"
)
SET /A "%~1=!len!"
EXIT /B


:StrLenNoLocalBrackets
(
   ECHO Loop %~3 / %Loops%
   (SET^ tmp=!%~2!)
   IF DEFINED tmp (
      SET /A "len=1"
      FOR %%P IN (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) DO (
         IF "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
            SET /A "len+=%%P"
            SET "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
         )
      )
   ) ELSE (
      SET /A "len=0"
   )
   SET /A "%~1=!len!"
   EXIT /B
)


:StrLenLocal
echo Loop %~3 / %Loops% & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
if defined tmp (
  set /a "len=1"
  for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
     if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
        set /a "len+=%%P"
        set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
     )
  )
) else (
    set /a "len=0"
)
endlocal & set /a "%~1=%len%" & exit /b


:StrLenLocalBrackets
(
   echo Loop %~3 / %Loops%
)
(
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
   if defined tmp (
      set /a "len=1"
      for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
         if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" (
            set /a "len+=%%P"
            set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
         )
      )
   ) else (
        set /a "len=0"
   )
)
(
   endlocal
   set /a "%~1=%len%"
   exit /b
)



:TimeStamp
SET /A %~1=1%time:~-5,-3%%time:~-2%
EXIT /B

:MeasureTime
SET /A %~1=!%~3!-!%~2!
IF !%~1! LSS 0 SET /A %~1=6000+!%~1!
IF "!%~1:~-2,-1!" == "" SET %~1=0!%~1!
IF "!%~1:~0,-2!" == "" SET %~1=0!%~1!
SET %~1=!%~1:~0,-2!.!%~1:~-2!sec
EXIT /B



:EndOfBatch
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :EOF



:LabelBrackets
(
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" .
   EXIT /B
   :LabelInsideLabelBrackets
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" .
   EXIT /B
)


:LabelBracketsWOExit
(
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" .
   :LabelInsideLabelBracketsWOExit
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" .
   EXIT /B
)



:PingOneHundredTimes
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
EXIT /B


:PingOneHundredTimesBrackets
(
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 50 >NUL
   EXIT /B
)



:DoItAgain
(
    TITLE A - StrLenNoLocal
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

    TITLE A - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

    TITLE A - StrLenLocal
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalA string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

    TITLE A - StrLenLocalBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

    REM Messure Timeout 5sec
    TITLE Timeout 5sec
    CALL :TimeStamp TimeoutStart
    timeout /NOBREAK /T 5 >NUL
    CALL :TimeStamp TimeoutEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime TimeoutTime TimeoutStart TimeoutEnd

    REM Ping...
    TITLE Ping 5000
    CALL :TimeStamp PingStart
    ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000 >NUL
    CALL :TimeStamp PingEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime PingTime PingStart PingEnd

    REM Ping 50 * 100
    TITLE PingOneHundredTimes
    CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesStart
    CALL :PingOneHundredTimes
    CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesEnd

    TITLE PingOneHundredTimesBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesBracketsStart
    CALL :PingOneHundredTimesBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp PingOneHundredTimesBracketsEnd

    CALL :MeasureTime PingOneHundredTimesTime PingOneHundredTimesStart PingOneHundredTimesEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime PingOneHundredTimesBracketsTime PingOneHundredTimesBracketsStart PingOneHundredTimesBracketsEnd

    REM Invert order

    TITLE B - StrLenLocalBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

    TITLE B - StrLenLocal
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenLocal LenDummyStrLenLocalB string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenLocalEnd

    TITLE B - StrLenNoLocalBrackets
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocalBrackets LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd

    TITLE B - StrLenNoLocal
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalStart
    FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%Loops%) DO CALL :StrLenNoLocal LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB string %%a
    CALL :TimeStamp StrLenNoLocalEnd

    TITLE Results
    ECHO.

    REM "Empty" Timestamp Measure
    CALL :TimeStamp TimestampStart
    CALL :TimeStamp TimestampEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime TimestampTime TimestampStart TimestampEnd

    ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenLocal            A :  !StrLenLocalTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
    ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalA! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsA!
    ECHO.

    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalTime StrLenNoLocalStart StrLenNoLocalEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime StrLenNoLocalBracketsStart StrLenNoLocalBracketsEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalTime StrLenLocalStart StrLenLocalEnd
    CALL :MeasureTime StrLenLocalBracketsTime StrLenLocalBracketsStart StrLenLocalBracketsEnd

    ECHO Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  !StrLenNoLocalTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  !StrLenNoLocalBracketsTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenLocal            B :  !StrLenLocalTime!
    ECHO Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  !StrLenLocalBracketsTime!
    ECHO StrLen !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenNoLocalBracketsB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalB! / !LenDummyStrLenLocalBracketsB!
    ECHO.
    ECHO "Empty" Timestamp Measure   :  !TimestampTime!
    ECHO Timeout /T 5                :  !TimeoutTime!
    ECHO ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000   :  !PingTime!
    ECHO PingOneHundredTimes         :  !PingOneHundredTimesTime!
    ECHO PingOneHundredTimesBrackets :  !PingOneHundredTimesBracketsTime!
    ECHO.
    EXIT /B
)
```

Output:

```
Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  20.40sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  16.82sec
Time StrLenLocal            A :  19.84sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  19.17sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191

Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  17.40sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  14.93sec
Time StrLenLocal            B :  17.64sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  18.52sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191

"Empty" Timestamp Measure   :  0.00sec
Timeout /T 5                :  5.16sec
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000   :  4.59sec
PingOneHundredTimes         :  50.50sec
PingOneHundredTimesBrackets :  50.50sec

...

Time StrLenNoLocal          A :  18.76sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  A :  16.76sec
Time StrLenLocal            A :  19.09sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    A :  19.67sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191

Time StrLenNoLocal          B :  18.24sec
Time StrLenNoLocalBrackets  B :  15.97sec
Time StrLenLocal            B :  18.63sec
Time StrLenLocalBrackets    B :  19.60sec
StrLen 8191 / 8191 / 8191 / 8191

"Empty" Timestamp Measure   :  0.00sec
Timeout /T 5                :  4.52sec
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 5000   :  4.56sec
PingOneHundredTimes         :  50.49sec
PingOneHundredTimesBrackets :  50.49sec


I'm called ":LabelBrackets" .
I'm called ":LabelInsideLabelBrackets" .

I'm called ":LabelBracketsWOExit" .
I'm called ":LabelBracketsWOExit" .
I'm called ":LabelInsideLabelBracketsWOExit" .
```

I came to the following conclusions:

```batch
ECHO %time%
timeout /T 5
ECHO %time%
```

- Is not exactly 5 seconds. ;)
- I got a nadir every time in "StrLenNoLocalBrackets".
- <s>I haven't found a chain of commands where anything within parentheses causes problems.</s> *****

```batch
:LongLabel
(
   ECHO I'm called "%~0" , because I have two extra lines.
   EXIT /B
)
```

- **LongLabel** is *still* the winner (as long as you know what you are doing). ;)

***Just a final revision** (I think I've already gone too far):

I still found a fly in the ointment:

```batch
@ECHO OFF

SET "S="
CALL :A

SET "S="
CALL :B

SET "S="
CALL :C

SET "S="
CALL :D

SET "S="
CALL :E

SET "S="
CALL :F


GOTO :EOF

:A
(
   SETLOCAL
   SET S=LOCALC
   ENDLOCAL
   ECHO %~0: %S% --^> Empty
   EXIT /B
)

:B
SETLOCAL
SET S=LOCALC
(
   ENDLOCAL
   ECHO %~0: %S% ^<-- Set
   EXIT /B
)

:C
(
   SETLOCAL
   SET S=LOCALC
   (
      ENDLOCAL
      ECHO %~0: %S% --^> Empty
      EXIT /B
   )
)

:D
(
   SETLOCAL
   SET S=LOCALC
)
(
   ENDLOCAL
   ECHO %~0: %S% ^<-- Set
   EXIT /B
)

:E
(
   SETLOCAL
   SET S=LOCALC
   ENDLOCAL & ECHO %~0: %S% --^> Empty & EXIT /B
)

:F
SETLOCAL
SET S=LOCALC
ENDLOCAL & ECHO %~0: %S% ^<-- Set & EXIT /B


ECHO End of batch (should not be echoed)
```

Note the difference between D, **E** and **F**

```
:A:  --> Empty
:B: LOCALC <-- Set
:C:  --> Empty
:D: LOCALC <-- Set
:E:  --> Empty
:F: LOCALC <-- Set
```

Which means you can't just bracket everything and expect the same result.

Comment: Maybe I should replace :F with :P to match all Sets to happy similes.