# How to write IF condition for numeric comparison in a windows batch file?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file to process some items. I am quite familiar with C/C++/Java, etc., but unfortunately for this use case I need to use a batch file that runs in Windows 11 Home. I am not very familiar with batch files and this site has been a life saver.

As part of what I am trying to do, I need to find the path for the parent folder containing the batch file. On this site, I found how to get the path for the batch file. But the solution provided to get the path for the parent didn't work.

So I thought of creating my own solution. For this, I need to do some numeric comparisons in the batch file. But the comparisons seem to keep failing (I presume they error out but I haven't actually checked errorvalue). I have looked at many examples on this site and others but am unable to find where I am going wrong.

Below is the snippet of the code where I am struggling. In the example that I am running it on, "stringlength" is set as 42 by the function that calculates the string length (the function is a copy paste of Jeb's answer at [How do you get the string length in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file)). Thinking that maybe the function was returning the result as a string rather than a numerical value, I have an explicit statement to assign variable "strLength" as a numerical expression.

When I run the below code, I hit the 1st 'PAUSE' with most values as expected. Upon continuing, the batch file just closes unexpectedly. It does not hit any of the other 'PAUSE' commands.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET MyPath=%~dp0
SET MyParentPath=%~dp0..\
SET searchString=!MyPath:~42,1!
SET MyPath=!MyPath:~0,-1!

CALL :strlen stringlength MyPath
CALL :strlen searchStringlength searchString
SET /A strLength=%stringlength%
SET /A schStrLength=%searchStringlength%
SET /A forStep=%schStrLength%-(2*%schStrLength%)
echo !MyPath!
echo %MyParentPath%
echo %strLength%
echo %searchString%
echo %schStrLength%
echo %forStep%
PAUSE
IF %strLength% GTR 0 (
echo "Inside 1st if"
PAUSE
    IF %strLength% GEQ %schStrLength% (
        echo "Inside 2nd if"
        PAUSE
        IF %forStep% LSS 0 (
            echo "Inside 3rd if"
            PAUSE
            SET strCopy=!MyPath!
            FOR /L %%G IN (%strLength%, %forStep%, 0) DO (
                SET strCopy=!strCopy:~0,%%G!
                echo !strCopy!
                PAUSE
                CALL :strlen strCopyLength !strCopy!
                SET /A strCpyLen=!strCopyLength!
                IF !strCpyLen! NEQ 0 (
                    IF !strCpyLen! GEQ !schStrLength! (
                        SET endStr=!strCopy:~(!strCpyLen!-1),(!schStrLength!)!
                        IF !endStr! NEQ "" (
                            IF !endStr! EQU "\" (
                                SET /A endLoc=!strCpyLen!
                                EXIT /B
                            )
                        )
                    ) ELSE (
                        SET /A endLoc=0
                        EXIT /B
                    )
                ) ELSE (
                    SET /A endLoc=0
                    EXIT /B
                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            echo "forstep issue"
            PAUSE
            SET /A endLoc=0
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo "searchstring len issue"
        PAUSE
        SET /A endLoc=0
    )
) ELSE (
    echo "strLength issue"
    PAUSE
    SET /A endLoc=0
)
SET MyParentPathCalc=!MyPath:~0,(%endLoc%-1)!
echo %MyParentPathCalc%
PAUSE

REM ********* function *****************************
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

The output of this code is:

> C:\Users\Beautiful\Documents\Outlook Files
>
> C:\Users\Beautiful\Documents\Outlook Files\..\
>
> 42
>
> \
>
> 1
>
> -1
>
> Press any key to continue...

[batch file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyu6e.png)

Thinking that maybe delayed expansion might work I tried the following next and got the same output.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET MyPath=%~dp0
SET MyParentPath=%~dp0..\
SET searchString=!MyPath:~42,1!
SET MyPath=!MyPath:~0,-1!

CALL :strlen stringlength MyPath
CALL :strlen searchStringlength searchString
SET /A strLength=!stringlength!
SET /A schStrLength=!searchStringlength!
SET /A forStep=!schStrLength!-(2*!schStrLength!)
echo !MyPath!
echo !MyParentPath!
echo !strLength!
echo !searchString!
echo !schStrLength!
echo !forStep!
PAUSE
IF !strLength! GTR 0 (
echo "Inside 1st if"
PAUSE
    IF !strLength! GEQ !schStrLength! (
        echo "Inside 2nd if"
        PAUSE
        IF !forStep! LSS 0 (
            echo "Inside 3rd if"
            PAUSE
            SET strCopy=!MyPath!
            FOR /L %%G IN (!strLength!, !forStep!, 0) DO (
                SET strCopy=!strCopy:~0,%%G!
                echo !strCopy!
                PAUSE
                CALL :strlen strCopyLength !strCopy!
                SET /A strCpyLen=!strCopyLength!
                IF !strCpyLen! NEQ 0 (
                    IF !strCpyLen! GEQ !schStrLength! (
                        SET endStr=!strCopy:~(!strCpyLen!-1),(!schStrLength!)!
                        IF !endStr! NEQ "" (
                            IF !endStr! EQU "\" (
                                SET /A endLoc=!strCpyLen!
                                EXIT /B
                            )
                        )
                    ) ELSE (
                        SET /A endLoc=0
                        EXIT /B
                    )
                ) ELSE (
                    SET /A endLoc=0
                    EXIT /B
                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            echo "forstep issue"
            PAUSE
            SET /A endLoc=0
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo "searchstring len issue"
        PAUSE
        SET /A endLoc=0
    )
) ELSE (
    echo "strLength issue"
    PAUSE
    SET /A endLoc=0
)
SET MyParentPathCalc=!MyPath:~0,(!endLoc!-1)!
echo !MyParentPathCalc!
PAUSE

REM ********* function *****************************
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

The output of this code is also:

> C:\Users\Beautiful\Documents\Outlook Files
>
> C:\Users\Beautiful\Documents\Outlook Files\..\
>
> 42
>
> \
>
> 1
>
> -1
>
> Press any key to continue...

Maybe a different notation might work. So I tried following 2 variations as well, but got the same result.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET MyPath=%~dp0
SET MyParentPath=%~dp0..\
SET searchString=!MyPath:~42,1!
SET MyPath=!MyPath:~0,-1!

CALL :strlen stringlength MyPath
CALL :strlen searchStringlength searchString
SET /A "strLength=!stringlength!"
SET /A "schStrLength=!searchStringlength!"
SET /A "forStep=!schStrLength!-(2*!schStrLength!)"
echo !MyPath!
echo !MyParentPath!
echo !strLength!
echo !searchString!
echo !schStrLength!
echo !forStep!
PAUSE
IF !strLength! GTR 0 (
echo "Inside 1st if"
PAUSE
    IF !strLength! GEQ !schStrLength! (
        echo "Inside 2nd if"
        PAUSE
        IF !forStep! LSS 0 (
            echo "Inside 3rd if"
            PAUSE
            SET strCopy=!MyPath!
            FOR /L %%G IN (!strLength!, !forStep!, 0) DO (
                SET strCopy=!strCopy:~0,%%G!
                echo !strCopy!
                PAUSE
                CALL :strlen strCopyLength !strCopy!
                SET /A "strCpyLen=!strCopyLength!"
                IF !strCpyLen! NEQ 0 (
                    IF !strCpyLen! GEQ !schStrLength! (
                        SET endStr=!strCopy:~(!strCpyLen!-1),(!schStrLength!)!
                        IF !endStr! NEQ "" (
                            IF !endStr! EQU "\" (
                                SET /A "endLoc=!strCpyLen!"
                                EXIT /B
                            )
                        )
                    ) ELSE (
                        SET /A "endLoc=0"
                        EXIT /B
                    )
                ) ELSE (
                    SET /A "endLoc=0"
                    EXIT /B
                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            echo "forstep issue"
            PAUSE
            SET /A "endLoc=0"
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo "searchstring len issue"
        PAUSE
        SET /A "endLoc=0"
    )
) ELSE (
    echo "strLength issue"
    PAUSE
    SET /A "endLoc=0"
)
SET MyParentPathCalc=!MyPath:~0,(!endLoc!-1)!
echo !MyParentPathCalc!
PAUSE

REM ********* function *****************************
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
SET MyPath=%~dp0
SET MyParentPath=%~dp0..\
SET searchString=!MyPath:~42,1!
SET MyPath=!MyPath:~0,-1!

CALL :strlen stringlength MyPath
CALL :strlen searchStringlength searchString
SET /A "strLength=%stringlength%"
SET /A "schStrLength=%searchStringlength%"
SET /A "forStep=%schStrLength%-(2*%schStrLength%)"
echo !MyPath!
echo %MyParentPath%
echo %strLength%
echo %searchString%
echo %schStrLength%
echo %forStep%
PAUSE
IF %strLength% GTR 0 (
echo "Inside 1st if"
PAUSE
    IF %strLength% GEQ %schStrLength% (
        echo "Inside 2nd if"
        PAUSE
        IF %forStep% LSS 0 (
            echo "Inside 3rd if"
            PAUSE
            SET strCopy=!MyPath!
            FOR /L %%G IN (%strLength%, %forStep%, 0) DO (
                SET strCopy=!strCopy:~0,%%G!
                echo !strCopy!
                PAUSE
                CALL :strlen strCopyLength !strCopy!
                SET /A "strCpyLen=!strCopyLength!"
                IF !strCpyLen! NEQ 0 (
                    IF !strCpyLen! GEQ !schStrLength! (
                        SET endStr=!strCopy:~(!strCpyLen!-1),(!schStrLength!)!
                        IF !endStr! NEQ "" (
                            IF !endStr! EQU "\" (
                                SET /A "endLoc=!strCpyLen!"
                                EXIT /B
                            )
                        )
                    ) ELSE (
                        SET /A "endLoc=0"
                        EXIT /B
                    )
                ) ELSE (
                    SET /A "endLoc=0"
                    EXIT /B
                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            echo "forstep issue"
            PAUSE
            SET /A "endLoc=0"
        )
    ) ELSE (
        echo "searchstring len issue"
        PAUSE
        SET /A "endLoc=0"
    )
) ELSE (
    echo "strLength issue"
    PAUSE
    SET /A "endLoc=0"
)
SET MyParentPathCalc=!MyPath:~0,(%endLoc%-1)!
echo %MyParentPathCalc%
PAUSE

REM ********* function *****************************
:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) else (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

As you can see, I am never able to get inside any IF (or even ELSE) conditions. I do not get anything after the results shown above. The batch file simply closes.

Any help/guidance on where I may be going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: all variable values in batch are strings. provided the content is only numerical (octal, hexidecimal or deximal), all should compare as expected when using if. The problem you describe is more like to be the result of attempting to expand the variable in a code block without delayed expansion, or possibly a missing parentheses. The code you have provided does not satisfy the minimal reproducable example needed to reproduce your described issue.

Comment: It would be helpful to tell us what values were displayed when the variables were `echo`ed.

Comment: Your first set of code works perfectly fine.  I get 10 printed 4 times.

Comment: After the `pause`, your `:strlen` label is run! This time it isn't `call`ed, and no arguments, `<resultVar>`, or `<stringVar>` are passed to it. It will run through the code, achieving nothing, then end the script with `exit /b`, hence "The batch file simply closes." This has nothing to do with `if` conditions, or numeric comparisons" your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. If you do not want it to auto run through the `:strlen` label code, you should either use a `goto` or alternate action before that label, or add a line at the start of that label which does something similar.

Comment: @T3RR0R Thx for pointing out the issue with my question. I have added the exact code. You can now copy paste it into a batch file and see the issue I am running into. Please note that delayed expansion is turned ON and I have tried using the delayed expansion but that does not seem to help either.

Comment: @Magoo, I have updated the question with the exact results.

Comment: @Compo The code never reaches the point you are raising the concern with. It fails before that. There is an echo statement before that pause you mention is the problem. That echo statement is never executed.

Comment: @Squashman Sorry I cropped the code snippet too much and you could not see the issue. I have pasted the exact code that fails now. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: @AA, you've completely changed the code now, so obviously previous comments, and possibly answers, are likely to be invalid now. However as you've not prevented the label code from being executed when reached, my advice is still valid. If you want proper help, you need to submit all of the code, or at the very least, an actual [mcve], we can all copy, and run with the same input as you, to replicate your stated issue.

Comment: The first line in the batch file should be `@echo off` to turn off the command echo mode. The second line should be `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` to enable command extensions as required and disable delayed variable expansion as not needed and problematic if the batch file directory path contains one or more exclamation marks. The third line should be `for %%I in ("%~dp0..") do set "MyParentPath=%%~fI"` replacing all other lines in your batch file and working even on batch file being in the root directory of a drive on which no parent directory exists.

Comment: @Compo Thx for pointing that out. Per your suggestion, I have added a goto :eof before the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SET endStr=!strCopy:~(!strCpyLen!-1),(!schStrLength!)!`

is far too complex an expression for `cmd`.

Had you run this routine from a `command prompt` as I asked, you would have seen the message

```
(!schStrLength! was unexpected at this time.
```

and since the block statement from

```
IF %strLength% GTR 0 (
```

to  the `)` of

```
)
SET MyParentPathCalc=!MyPath:~0,(!endLoc!-1)!
```

failed the parser's validation, `cmd` generated the error message but since you weren't running a `command prompt` window, you wouldn't see it.

The `set` statement needs to be something like

```
SET /a xyz=strCpyLen-1
CALL SET "endStr=%%strCopy:~!xyz!,!schStrLength!%%"
```

so that `set` sees the result of the calculation (`xyz`) and `schStrLength` as its startlocation and length-to-extract parameters. Since these are instantaneous values, then it's necessary to `call` the `set` which does the calculation

```
SET "endStr=%strCopy:~currentvalueofxyz,currentvalueofschStrLength%"
```

in a sub-shell.

The code will then be syntactically valid and your `pause`s will then be executed.

`cmd` is a very old language and very particular about syntax. It has been expanded and has had facilities added on over the last 40 years, with each new addition needing to be backwards-compatible.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response and for the pointer on running the batch file from CMD directly for debugging. This definitely helps me quite a bit so that I can try and debug issues on my own or ask the right questions!

Answer (score 0):

First issue: The caret in `set^ tmp=!%~2!` is superfluous. It appears harmless; the code works whether it is present or not.

Next: `tmp` is a variable which contains the location of a directory which may be used to create temporary files. Usually, `tmp` and `temp` contain the same directory-name. Programs use the setting when a temporary file is required. Some programs use `tmp`, others use `temp` so BOTH variables are set to the same value in order that a program can reliably determine which directory to use for its temporary files.

Hence, `tmp` and `temp` are some of the variable-names that should NOT be changed. Simply use a different name.

Next, any code within a pair of parentheses is known as a "code block". `cmd` "parses" the code block, then executes it if it is valid. Part of this parsing process is to replace `%var%` with its current value at parse time - before execution.

If `delayedexpansion` has been invoked, then the parser will ALSO replace `!var!` with its current value (or "instantaneous value" or "dynamic value") at execution time - as it might change as the program progresses through a loop.

Hence, given `delayedexpansion` has been invoked, `%var%` and `!var!` will be the same EXCEPT in a code block where the value of `var` is varied.

Consequently, the only place in your code where the `!var!` syntax appears necessary is for `tmp` (which you *are* going to rename, aren't you?) and `len` (had you needed to use its value) in the subroutine.

Using `!var!` also acts as a programming aid, saying "watch this variable closely - its value may vary as the loop progresses"

Note that `set /a` acts a little differently. It always uses the current value of its argument, unless the argument contains `%var%`, where that value will be replaced by the initial value by the parser.

`set /a` evaluates the argument and sets `errorlevel` to non-zero if it cannot be resolved to an integer. Whereas the calculation appears to be performed in 64-bit, the lower 32 bits of the result are then taken as a 32-bit signed integer, converted to a string and assigned to the variable.

`set "var=value"` is used to assign a string value. This syntax ignores trailing spaces on the line which can cause hard-to-find problems if `set var=value` is used.

Your line `SET searchString="abcdefgh"` assigns the value `"abcdefgh"` to the variable, not `abcdefgh` as some believe. The length of `searchstring` as calculated by the `:strlen` routine will thus be `10`, not `8` as you might expect since the variable contains the quotes.

The subroutine uses `set thatvariablethatyouregoingtorename=!%~2!`, in the apparent belief that the `~` removes the quotes from the *value of* the second parameter. It doesn't. It's executed as `set var=thevalueof(dequoted argument 2)`, not `set var=dequoted(thevalueof(argument 2))`. Hence, `CALL :strlen stringlength searchString` and `CALL :strlen stringlength "searchString"` will act identically.

The fact that the batch `closes unexpectedly` indicates that you are running the code from a `shortcut` and some statement following the `pause` is invalid.

When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will close if a syntax-error is found or the script runs to completion. You *can* put a `pause` after statements & home in on the error, but better to [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) & run your batch from there so that the window remains open & any (error) messages will be displayed.

Since your post appears to work and produce the results that **I** expect, it may be that you have over-cropped the original, leading to misleading conclusions.

Comment: Thx for your analysis. The issue is not with the strlen function. You were correct in assuming I had overcropped the code in my original post. I have edited it to provide the exact code that is failing. You can copy/cd\paste it into a batch file to see what I see.